# How to subset two files based on one column in common?

Tags: r, subset

How to subset two files based on one column in common?

I have two text files that have one column with same structure, which is a `date` `year-m-d`.

```
   > head(wg)
        date  valu1   
 40034 2008-01-01 0.323   
 40058 2008-01-02 0.314 
  > head(reg)
    date      dval
 1 2008-01-01        0.225
 2 2008-01-02        0.235
```

To read one file:

```
 wg= read.table("C:\\Users\\wg.txt", sep ='' , header =TRUE)
```

But one of the two files has some dates missing so the number of rows is different  between `wg` and `reg`and I cannot do any calculation. Now what I need is to subset  `wg and reg`  where they are both available (based on `date`)  ,as a result, both `wg` and `reg` have the same date and number of rows. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It seems that you need to use wg$date %in% reg$date

Comment: Can you explain how please? and can you expand it as an asswer

Comment: @Barry in case he doesn't get back to you soon, the complete command would be `wg <- wg[wg$date %in% reg$date,]`

Comment: Thanks @Mattrition but i got this  `wg : [1] date  mint  valu1     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data example

```
A<-as.Date(c("2008-01-01", "2008-01-02", "2008-01-03"))
valA<-as.numeric(c(0.333, 0.232, 0.123))
B<-as.Date(c("2008-01-01", "2008-01-02", "2008-01-04"))
valB<-as.numeric(c(0.225, 0.124, 0.345))

wg<-data.frame(A, valA)
reg<-data.frame(B, valB)

v1<-wg$A %in% reg$B
```

The selected rows for wg:

```
wg[v1, ]
```

To get the row numbers for reg you need to run the %in% the other way around

Comment: Many thanks but the problem is that in one of my files there is no `1 2 3 4` as you can see for `wg` so it is not working for my files.

Comment: What is the error message that you get? is wg of the class data.frame?

Comment: no error but `V1 = integer (0)`. the problem is in `wg` there is no `1 2 3 4` but for example `40034` see head(wg) in my question please.

Comment: I got all as `FALSE`  I think the problem is that the dates in wg are between quotation marks `""` while `reg` there is no `""`  see : `> head(wg$date)
[1] "2008-01-01" "2008-01-02" "2008-01-03" "2008-01-04" "2008-01-05" "2008-01-06"
> head(reg$date)
[1] 2008-01-01 2008-01-02 2008-01-03 2008-01-04 2008-01-05 2008-01-06`

Comment: @Barry: that sounds like a problem of class. Test if one is a character/factor vector and the other one a date vector. They should both be of the same class.

Comment: you can turn it into class Date: reg$date<-as.Date(reg$date) .